# Linq All Vs Foreach

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Hi I am trying to understand differences between All and ForEach in Linq.

I know that All is used for checking a condition and returns bool if the predicate is satisfied. But when i have an assignment inside the predicate it simply works fine and donot complain.

What is the use of ForEach in that case?  Or what cases makes  it use of ForEach

It might be little silly but need to know significance

Comment: `ForEach` is not part of LINQ. LINQ is functional, therefore it has no place for something like a `ForEach`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is actually no `ForEach` in LINQ (on purpose).  There is a `List<T>.ForEach` method, which runs an action on each object in the list.

The main difference is `All` is a filter - it returns true if all of the items match a predicate.  `List<T>.ForEach` exists to create side effects - you run some operation on each item within the list.

In general, I'd avoid queries with LINQ that cause side effects (ie: don't do the operation in the query), and instead put them in a `foreach` loop afterwards.  This makes the intention very clear, which helps maintainability.

Note that `List<T>.ForEach` was actually removed from the WinRT framework, since it really doesn't add a lot of value.  Eric Lippert wrote a [great article on the subject](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx) of using `foreach` instead of `List<T>.ForEach`.

Comment: I had wondered about the possibility of LINQ having a foreach as well, nice link to that article